# Display new info when IE is detected

Tags: seo

not sure if I should ask this here but I am creating a new site using alot of the new technologies that arn't found in IE or older browsers so I have added a bit javascript that loads a new css file when they are detected and within this I hide the main page information and unhide a div which says update your browser, this works great but I have reservations regarding google rankings and SEO. Because the original content of my site is hid when IE is detected will this still show for google or will I get penalised?

Answer (score 1):

Google does not test your site using multiple browsers and therefore will not count negatively. Your counted content is the same content rendered using the Google Fetch URL tool. However ideally if you shouldn't hide 'text or image' content if you plan to provide a fallback for users using obsolete browsers, otherwise it seems a little pointless.

The only things that you should be hiding are particular GUI elements, not the text, or images.